# How can I compress the X axis in a ggplot()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

First the reproducible example:

**Data:**

```
grid_tbl <- bind_cols(x = seq(from = -10, to = 10, by = 0.05), 
          y = seq(from = -10, to = 10, by = 0.05))

sine_points_vec <- map(grid_tbl$x, sinpi) %>% unlist()

sine_plot_tbl <- bind_cols(grid_tbl$x, sine_points_vec) %>% rename(x = `...1`, y = `...2`)
```

**The Plot:**

```
    sine_plot_tbl %>% 
    select(y,x) %>% 
    rename(y = x, x = y) %>% 
       ggplot(aes(x = y, y = x)) +
        coord_fixed(ratio = 0.8) + 
#        coord_flip() + 
        geom_line(color = "red") +
        geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "blue") +
        labs(
            title = "Inverse Sine Relation Plot",
            caption = "Vertical line passes through curve at many points"
        )
```

**The Goal:**

I'm looking for a way to compress the X axis by a fixed percent in order to change the appearance of the plotted curve so as to make the peaks of the curve flatter.

For example, in the posted code the coord_fixed(ratio = 0.8) produces the desired appearance, but if I uncomment the next line to flip the coordinates, the flattening is discarded. I get this message:

*Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.*

I'm not looking to transform the values that produce the curve, merely to change the appearance. If you swap the comment marker between the coord_fixed() function and the coord_flip() function, you'll see the challenge.

I tried adding coord_fixed() to the ggplot. I expected the curve's appearance to flatten.

What actually happened was that the subsequent coord_flip() function overwrote that.

Answer (score 1):

Slight variation using expansion to widen the range of the x axis shown, here making the two sides 5x as wide as the data.

```
sine_plot_tbl %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = y, y = x)) +
  geom_path(color = "red") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, color = "blue") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(5,5))) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 2) + 
  labs(
    title = "Inverse Sine Relation Plot",
    caption = "Vertical line passes through curve at many points"
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Each plot can only have one `coord` layer. But instead of `coord_flip` you could switch `x` and `y` and use `orientation="y"` in `geom_line`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn=FALLSE)

sine_plot_tbl %>%
  select(y, x) %>%
  rename(y = x, x = y) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_line(color = "red", orientation = "y") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, color = "blue") +
  coord_fixed(xlim = c(-5, 5), ratio = .8) +
  labs(
    title = "Inverse Sine Relation Plot",
    caption = "Vertical line passes through curve at many points"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This approach does the same thing as my original tack and does not fix the issue with the width of the plot itself. In the current state, the x-axis tick mark labels overlap. I'm hoping to spread the x-axis without also spreading the width of the curve. Any thoughts?

Comment: I just have made an edit. If I understand you correctly, i.e. spreading the x axis without affecting the curve you might achieve your desired result by increasing the limits via the `coord_xxx` (or the scale). You might also consider switching to the default coord_cartesian and of course does the same also work with coords_flip. But for both you probably have to use higher limits.

Comment: I've decided to use your approach as it is easier to fiddle with the width of the plot and the peakedness of the curves. I have made this change: coord_fixed(xlim = c(-1.5, 1.5), ratio = 0.25)